# How to use C++ to draw a polygon using an array of 3d points

Tags: c++, graphics, 3d

I would like to get help in using C++ in order to draw a polygon using an array of 3d points. I already sort my array so that my points are arranged in order(i.e one points follow the other). Any help will be appreciated in advance. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Unless I am misreading the question, you will need a 3D-Rendering API such as [Direct3D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Direct3D) or [OpenGL](http://www.opengl.org/). There are other options, but those two are by far the most popular.

You do have to be aware that Direct3D is available only on Windows, while OpenGL is supported on most major platforms. But Direct3D is part of DirectX which is an entire package of multimedia APIs while OpenGL is strictly graphics (aside from OpenAL for audio).

Whichever you choose, there are countless tutorials online about drawing basic polygons that are just a quick Google search away.

Comment: Perhaps consider [VTK](http://www.vtk.org/). It's a very accessible wrapper to OpenGL. I've found it easy to learn.

C++ example for drawing a polygon [here](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/GeometricObjects/Polygon)